# Get calendar week id in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to get current and current - 7 week id in sql server.
So far i can get that, but for week id under 10 is a problem for me.

```
DECLARE @CurrentWeek nvarchar(6),@CurrentWeek7 nvarchar(6)
SET @CurrentWeek = CAST(datepart(yy, GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4))+''+CAST(datepart(ww, GETDATE()) AS CHAR(2))
SET @CurrentWeek7 = CAST(datepart(yy, DATEADD(WEEK, -7, GETDATE())) AS CHAR(4)) +''+CAST(datepart(ww, DATEADD(WEEK, -7, GETDATE())) AS CHAR(2))
```

Problem is that i get for example calendar week id without 0 between year and week number for week number under 10.

20199 instead of 201909. I want this to work also for week number bigger than 10, for example 201911

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: I ***assume*** that this isn't what you're after then: `SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()), DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(WEEK,-7, GETDATE()));`.

Comment: What do you mean `week ID`? What you posted is a custom string containing a year and week number.It's not some kind of ID, nor is it something that specifies a specific week in a year

Comment: select DATEPART(dw,getDate())

Comment: `select year(getdate()) *100 +datepart(wk,getdate())` to get the Year + WeekNumber as a number

Comment: I already found out myself how to do this. select year(getdate()) *100 +datepart(wk,getdate()) is the best answer for me problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RIGHT` trick to force a left-sided 0 when the week day is 9 or less.

```
DECLARE 
    @CurrentWeek nvarchar(6),
    @CurrentWeek7 nvarchar(6)

DECLARE @TodayLastWeek DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())

SET @CurrentWeek = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())) 
        + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())), 2)

SET @CurrentWeek7 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @TodayLastWeek)) 
        + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(WEEK, @TodayLastWeek)), 2)

SELECT
    CurrentWeek = @CurrentWeek,
    CurrentWeek7 = @CurrentWeek7
```

Result:

```
CurrentWeek CurrentWeek7
201909      201908
```

**PD**: Please check Panagiotis' comment, his solution is faster and simpler.

Comment: Yes his solution is simpler, i also found my self the the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of logic like this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentWeek nvarchar(6),
        @CurrentWeek7 nvarchar(6);

SET @CurrentWeek = dateadd(day,
                           1 - datepart(weekday, getdate()),
                           convert(date, getdate())
                          );

SET @CurrentWeek7 = dateadd(week, -7, @CurrentWeek);
```

The key idea is that the historical week should be based on the definition of the current week.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CurrentWeek nvarchar(6),@CurrentWeek7 nvarchar(6)
    SET @CurrentWeek = CAST(datepart(yy, GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4))* 100+''+CAST(datepart(ww, GETDATE()) AS CHAR(2))
    SET @CurrentWeek7 = CAST(datepart(yy, DATEADD(WEEK, -7, GETDATE())) AS CHAR(4))* 100 +''+CAST(datepart(ww, DATEADD(WEEK, -7, GETDATE())) AS CHAR(2))
```